# how do i sort a leader board and show the top 5

Tags: python, string, integer, css-float, leaderboard

i've been trying to make a leader board for the top 5 scores in order to highest to lowest. however i've ran into a problem and unable to solve it.
this is what i have so far:

```
import time
limit = 5 # you can set out the limit here.

def leaderboard():
    scores = [] 
    print ("\n") 
    print ("⬇ Check out the leaderboard ⬇")
    #LEADERBOARD SECTION 
    for line in open('H_Highscore.txt', 'r'):
        if not line:
           pass
        else:
           *name, score = line.split(",")
    score = int(float(score)) # clean and convert to int to order the scores using sort()
    scores.append((score, name))
        
    sorted_scores = sorted(scores, reverse = True) # this will sort the scores based on the first position of the tuples
    
    for register in sorted_scores[:limit]:
        # I will use string formating, take a look at it, it is really usefull.
        text = f"%s: %s pts" % (register[1], register[0])
        print(text)
l = open ("H_Highscore.txt", "r")
file_contents = l.read()
print(file_contents)
l.close()
ans = input("does your score beat the top 5?(Y/N) ")
if ans == 'y' or ans == "Y" : 
    user = str(input("Enter a (user)name: "))
    file = open ("H_Highscore.txt", "a")
    score = str(input("enter you score: "))
    file.write("\n")
    file.write(user)
    file.write(",")
    file.write(str(score)) # (int(x)) can not be written
    file.write("pts")
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    leaderboard()
else: 
    print("unlucky kentucky")
```

an error comes up: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(A number that i type in for the score)pts/n'.
thank you in advance

Comment: Which integer did you expect the string `'(A number that i type in for the score)pts/n'` to be converted to?

Comment: this one in the definition:
score = int(float(score))
this one is causing problems

Comment: Yes. The problem is that if you enter the string `'(A number that i type in for the score)pts/n'`, Python doesn't know which number you mean. You should instead enter a string that actually represents a number, for example `'3'`, or `'17'`.

Comment: that's not what i type in. i type in a number. but the number is a string and i want to turn it into a interger